# Error in Python plugin for qgis

Tags: python, plugins, qgis

I'm following a tutorial for developing a plugin for `qgis`, but I'm stuck in a error, when trying to insert a text in a textbox window. The code is as demonstrated [here](http://www.qgisworkshop.org/html/workshop/plugins_tutorial.html#tie-qgspoint-output-to-the-gui)

Class vector_selectbypointdialog.py:

```
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
    from ui_vector_selectbypoint import Ui_vector_selectbypoint
    # create the dialog for zoom to point
    class vector_selectbypointDialog(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
        self.ui = Ui_vector_selectbypoint()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

    def setTextBrowser(self, output):
        self.ui.txtFeedback.setText(output)

    def clearTextBrowser(self):
        self.ui.txtFeedback.clear()
```

Class vector_selectbypoint.py:

under **init** create the object like this:

```
# create our GUI dialog
self.dlg = vector_selectbypointDialog()
```

And the method that handles to insert the text:

```
handleMouseDown(self, point, button):
        self.dlg.clearTextBrowser()
        self.dlg.setTextBrowser( str(point.x()) + " , " +str(point.y()) )
```

The error is:

> handleMouseDown
>       self.dlg.clearTextBrowser()
>   AttributeError: 'vector_selectbypointdialog' object has no attribute 'clearTextBrowser'

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to rename your PyQt text browser widget txtFeedback?

Comment: Yes. The problem is about clearTextBrowser, that does exist in the code but is not detected in handleMouseDown.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and solved it : you probably have a mixing of tab and space characters in class vector_selectbypointDialog (clearTextBrowser becomes a subfunction in init()).

Indent correctly your code in vector_selectbypointdialog.py and it will work ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, something is wrong in this example.

Instead of:

```
    self.dlg.clearTextBrowser()
    self.dlg.setTextBrowser( str(point.x()) + " , " +str(point.y()) )
```

just use:

```
    self.dlg.ui.txtFeedback.clear()
    self.dlg.ui.txtFeedback.setText( str(point.x()) + " , " +str(point.y()) )
```